# TypeError: pandas._libs.tslibs.period.PeriodMixin.__new__(PeriodArray)

Tags: python, pandas, pickle, statsmodels, arima

I am getting the following error when trying to unpickle an ARIMA model I had made.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 42, in <module>
    loaded_model = joblib.load('./models/arima2.model')
  File "/Users/sparshbohra/Desktop/adsl/cb/server/cb_analytics_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 587, in load
    obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
  File "/Users/sparshbohra/Desktop/adsl/cb/server/cb_analytics_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 506, in _unpickle
    obj = unpickler.load()
  File "/Users/sparshbohra/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 1088, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)
  File "/Users/sparshbohra/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 1436, in load_reduce
    stack[-1] = func(*args)
  File "stringsource", line 7, in pandas._libs.tslibs.period.__pyx_unpickle_PeriodMixin
TypeError: pandas._libs.tslibs.period.PeriodMixin.__new__(PeriodArray): PeriodArray is not a subtype of pandas._libs.tslibs.period.PeriodMixin
```

The code I have written is:

```
import joblib
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMAResults

loaded_model = joblib.load('./models/arima2.model')
```

Comment: This is like asking "why does English not have the word *"'skep"?* It just doesn't. What are you actually hoping to accomplish?

Comment: Well fyi, the function actually exists. https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMAResults.load.html.

Comment: Then you are not actually `import`ing that particular function correctly, but you are not showing us that part of the code.

Comment: These are the relevant imports. Kindly suggest what edits should be made.

Comment: How did you create `arima2.model`?  Is this environment the same as the one where it was created? Version mismatches can cause pickles to fail to load.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and i didn't find solution so i used pickel package to solve this problem

```py
# Import pickle Package
import pickle

# Save the Modle to file in the current working directory
Pkl_Filename = "Pickle_RL_Model.pkl"  

with open(Pkl_Filename, 'wb') as file:  
    pickle.dump(LR_Model, file)

# Load the Model back from file
with open(Pkl_Filename, 'rb') as file:  
    Pickled_LR_Model = pickle.load(file)

Pickled_LR_Model
```